Stepper motor not moving but driver showing lights
I am trying to get a stepper motor to work, I am following this tutorial and I have the same stepper motor/driver https://www.youngwonks.com/blog/How-to-use-a-stepper-motor-with-the-Raspberry-Pi-Pico
Here is the code:
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

pins = [
    Pin(15, Pin.OUT), #1
    Pin(14, Pin.OUT), #2
    Pin(16, Pin.OUT), #3
    Pin(17, Pin.OUT), #4
]

full_step_sequence = [
    [1,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1]
]

while True:
    for step in full_step_sequence:
        for i in range(len(pins)):
            pins[i].value(step[i])
            sleep(0.5)

and the wiring

Hope the cables aren't too confusing, I am using the same setup as the tutorial
I am pretty sure that the setup is correct since I do get flashing lights in a sequence on the driver board, the stepper motor itself is also getting warm and I can feel some vibrations. However, there is no actual movement from the motor and I can't see an error; am I missing somehting or is that a sign of a broken motor?
edit: The tutorial is using the 3V3 port on the pico, which I guess is incorrect, it should rather be the VBUS for 5V. I tried both without success.

Did you try slowing down your code to check the correct LED-sequence? That way you can at least verify if the cabling is correct.

yes, I have, it seems to be fine

Can you provide a datasheet of the H-bridge and Motor?

There is a difference at the last line of code: sleep(0.5) or utime.sleep(0.001)

It's a 28BYJ-48 stepper motor, here is the datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/stepd-01-data-sheet-1143075.pdf

@Another_coder please update the post ... do not write info in a comment
